# trying to understand SIMPLEST CASE of Python class and self

Tags: python, class, self

I'm pretty new to Python, but learning.  I'm trying to sort out class and self after talking to professor today.  Here's a SIMPLE experiment I am trying with one "calling", Main program, and a separate class with called functions, called from Main and called from inside the class.  I've written enough to try to test some of the flexibilities but I'm now debugging and I fear I'll put A BUNCH of stupid garbage in this to try to get it to run.  Can someone see what needs to be done please, to get it to run without any excess complication?  Thanks!

```
#######################################################################################################
#
# BoxDemoMain.py calling program
# demonstration of using and calling BoxClass.py pgm
#
#
import numpy as np
import BoxClassPgm
#
#
def ReportBoxDimensions(anySizeBox):
    Ht = anySizeBox.boxHeight
    Wd = anySizeBox.boxWidth
    Dp = anySizeBox.boxDepth
    print "The Height, Width, and Depth of this box is " + str(Ht) + "," + str(Wd) + "," + str(Dp)
    print "The Surface Area of this box is " + str(BoxClassPgm.BoxClass(anySizeBox).CalcSurfArea())
    print "The Volume of this box is " + str(BoxClassPgm.BoxClass(anySizeBox).CalcVolume())
#
#
largeBox = BoxClass(6,8,4)
mediumBox = BoxClass(4,5,3)
smallBox = BoxClass(3,3,3)
#
#
ReportBoxDimensions(largeBox)
ReportBoxDimensions(mediumBox)
ReportBoxDimensions(smallBox)
#######################################################################################################
#
# BoxClassPgm.py class program
# class demonstration
#
#
import numpy as np
#
#
class BoxClass:

    def __init__(self,boxHeight=0,boxWidth=0,boxDepth=0):
        self.boxHeight = boxHeight
        self.boxWidth = boxWidth
        self.boxDepth = boxDepth

    def CalcVolume(self):
        print "height is " + str(self.boxHeight)
        boxVol = self.boxHeight * self.boxWidth * self.boxDepth
        return boxVol

    def CalcSurfArea(self):
        areaOf3Faces = BoxClass().CalcFaceAreas()
        boxSurfArea = 2 * areaOf3Faces
        return boxSurfArea

    def CalcFaceAreas(self):
        frontBack = self.boxHeight * self.boxWidth
        leftRight = self.boxHeight * self.boxDepth
        topBottom = self.boxWidth * self.boxDepth
        box3Faces = frontBack + leftRight + topBottom
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question? Are you getting an error? If so, please share.

Comment: sure, sorry if it is vague....In the BoxClass class (lower half), in the CalcVolume function, right now I am getting an error pointing to the boxVol calculation.  It says "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instance' and 'int'.  That is the specific bug at the moment, but I'm also wondering, is the structure of this code totally crazy, or is it somehow close to how a class might be utilized?

Comment: Add that information to the question as an edit, not as a comment

Comment: But the problem arises from you passing `anySizeBox`  which already is a `BoxClass` object, to a `BoxClass` constructor, then using that instances getVol method, but that will try to multiply that object with an `int` which isn't a defined operation. Your class seems reasonable, but it doesn't seem like you are really grokking the point of a class.

Comment: Thanks juanpa for the insight.  Yes I agree on the grokking, I'm struggling to "get it".  I think the class technique is to create object instances with some common characteristics, so you can then share methods that can be applied to those objects.  In this case, a box, a specific one, in this case large or medium or small, are all boxes with 3 dimensions.  Being 3-dim, square items with height, width, and depth, it is true then that they call can share the same volume and surface area calcs, right?  Isn't that the simplest idea behind (the use of) a class?